# EXTjs grid model json noob

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

What am I doing wrong? Of all the fields displayed in the grid only Working Group. EXTjs 4.2.1.
Tried different variants that have been found here, but, alas, nothing has helped understand what is wrong here.

```
Ext.define('myModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'WorckGroup', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Statistics', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'Specialist', type: 'string', mapping: 'Statistics.Specialist' },
        { name: 'ScallCount', type: 'int', mapping: 'Statistics.SCallCount' },
        { name: 'AverageDuration', type: 'auto', mapping: 'Statistics.AverageDuration' }
    ]
});


var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'myModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/omnireports/ajaxgrid',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});


var basegrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    columns: [
    { header: 'WG', width: 200, dataIndex: 'WorckGroup' },
    { header: 'SP', dataIndex: 'Specialist' },
    { header: 'SCC', dataIndex: 'SCallCount' },
    { header: 'AD', dataindex: 'AverageDuration' }
    ],    });
```

json

```
[
{"WorckGroup":"3D",
    "Statistics":[
    {"Specialist":"В А","SCallCount":64,"AverageDuration":0.1136067},
    {"Specialist":"К Т","SCallCount":170,"AverageDuration":0.1045816}]
{"WorckGroup":"SD",
    "Statistics":[
    {"Specialist":"B A","SCallCount":197,"AverageDuration":0.1364689}]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mappings don't make sense. `Statistics` is an array, so `Statistics.Specialist` doesn't map to anything.

Your root for the reader should probably be `WorckGroup.Statistics` and you should include the `WorckGroup` in each item.

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'WorckGroup.Statistics'
}
```

Then remove the mapping from each field in the model.

Comment: Could you give an example of an array? I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: I don't really follow what you're asking. Do you mean what is an array?

Comment: How to properly parse this json to represent it in the grid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I gave incorrect JSON data. Fixed in the original message.